# stop vb.net from turning 02/02/2011 to 2/2/2011

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

For some reason vb keeps changing my dates format and removes the 0s at first this wasnt a problem but it really messes up my sorting in my gridview.

```
Dim aftersubtraction As Date
aftersubtraction = departuredate.AddDays(-dates1.Text)
dates.Add(aftersubtraction.AddDays(-gracep.Text))
```

Comment: Dates don't have formats; strings have formats. It's only when your date is converted to a string that a format is applied. If changing the formatting of a date messes up your sort, you are sorting wrong. You should sort based on the date value, not on its string value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateTime objects store their variables as integers. It will always engage in this behavior. To prevent it, you need to format the date as a string of your choosing before you send it where-ever you send it:

```
aftersubtraction.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't confuse how a date is stored internally (doesn't really matter), to how you *display* it.

"Feb 2nd 2011" is the same date as "02/02/2011" or "2/2/11".

When you have a date variable and want to display it a certain way, you should use the correct format string - either a [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) or a [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) one.

In your case you seem to want this:

```
Dim outputDate as String = myDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") ' European/UK style
Dim outputDate as String = myDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") ' US style
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Joel said - you shouldn't be sorting on the string representation of a date object - you should be sorting on the date value itself, then it won't matter how it's sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Region and Language settings to your correct culture this will probably solve your issue, but if you have problems with sorting dates in a gridview you might be passing a datasource that stores the date as a string.